# golang cgo exit status 2 on Windows

Tags: windows, go, cgo, exitstatus

#### Attempt

I want to compile the following snippet on my `Windows 8.1` machine with `Go 1.8.1` installed.

```
package main

/*
int theAnswer() {
    return 42;
}
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.theAnswer())
}
```

Here is a working [Ideone Snippet](http://ideone.com/jh6uGP).

#### Problem

Whilst running the snippet in `ideone` works as expected, the compilation on my own machine fails somehow:

```
$ CC=gcc GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=windows go build -x
WORK=C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build775642990
mkdir -p $WORK\_\D_\dev\workspaces\go\src\github.com\nopmind\_obj\
mkdir -p $WORK\_\D_\dev\workspaces\go\src\github.com\nopmind\_obj\exe\
cd D:\dev\workspaces\go\src\github.com\nopmind

CGO_LDFLAGS="-g" "-O2" "C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\cgo.exe" 
-objdir "C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\go-build775642990\\_\\D_\\dev\\workspaces\\go\\src\\github.com\\nopmind\\_obj\\" 
-importpath _/D_/dev/workspaces/go/src/github.com/nopmind 
-- -I "C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\go-build775642990\\_\\D_\\dev\\workspaces\\go\\src\\github.com\\nopmind\\_obj\\" 
-g -O2 Test.go

go build _/D_/dev/workspaces/go/src/github.com/nopmind: C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\cgo.exe: exit status 2
```

(`$ go build -x` gives same output)

After googling for a few hours without any useful results I'm now hardstuck on this.

#### Environment

- OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- Go: 1.8.1
- MingW: [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) installed through [WinBuilds](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds)

#### Question

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening ?

My personal guess is that something is wrong with the MingW installation. If so I'd appreciate a short explanation how to properly set MingW up for cgo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works on Windows 10 and 7 and Linux. For example, on Windows 10, using [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) for MinGW,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]

>go version
go version devel +dc0f0ab Thu Apr 13 18:20:38 2017 +0000 windows/amd64

>gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

>type answer.go
package main

/*
int theAnswer() {
    return 42;
}
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println(C.theAnswer())
}

>go run answer.go
42

>
```

I have never used [Win-builds](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds).

Comment: Okey, i now tried with `TDM-GCC` (totaly forgot about that one) and it works !

Seems like the `Win-Build` package isnt supported. Thank you !